# what's the difference between rdd from PythonRDD and ParallelCollectionRDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am learning how to program with Spark in Python and struggle with one problem.

The problem is that I have a PythonRDD loaded as id and description:

```
pythonRDD.take(1)
## [('b000jz4hqo', ['clickart', '950', '000', 'premier', 'image', 'pack', 'dvd', 'rom', 'broderbund'])]
```

And ParallelCollectionRDD loaded as id and description:

```
paraRDD.take(1)
## [('b000jz4hqo', ['clickart', '950', '000', 'premier', 'image', 'pack', 'dvd', 'rom', 'broderbund'])]
```

I can do a count on the paraRDD like this:

```
paraRDD.map(lambda l: (l[0],len(l[1]))).reduce(lambda a,b: a[1] + b[1])
```

or simply

```
paraRDD.reduce(lambda a,b: len(a[1]) + len(b[1]))
```

but on pythonRDD it ran into bug, the bug says:

> "TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**'".

```
def countTokens(vendorRDD):
    return vendorRDD.map(lambda l: (l[0],len(l[1]))).reduce(lambda a,b: a[1] + b[1])
```

Any idea on how this happened would be appreciated?!

Answer (score 1):

Difference between `PythonRDD` and `ParallelCollectionRDD` is completely irrelevant here. Your code is just wrong.

`reduce` method takes an associative and commutative function with the following signature:

```
(T, T) => T
```

In other words both arguments and returned object have to be of the same type and an order of operations and a parenthesizing cannot affect the final result. Function you pass to the `reduce` simply doesn't satisfy these criteria.

To make it work you'll need something like this:

```
rdd.map(lambda l: len(l[1])).reduce(lambda x, y: x + y)
```

or even better:

```
from operator import add

rdd.values().map(len).reduce(add)
```

Comment: Hi, but it works with the ParallelCollectionRDD using the same map and reduce function. That's what bothers me here..

Comment: If you're in doubt take a look at my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/35190202/1560062 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/35132794/1560062 These should illustrate why incorrect usage of fold-like methods can give unpredictable results depending on a data distribution.

Comment: So what is the difference between the two